# Python: strip pair-wise column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strip

I have a DataFrame with columns that look like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['(NYSE_close, close)','(NYSE_close, open)','(NYSE_close, volume)', '(NASDAQ_close, close)','(NASDAQ_close, open)','(NASDAQ_close, volume)'])

df:
(NYSE_close, close) (NYSE_close, open) (NYSE_close, volume) (NASDAQ_close, close) (NASDAQ_close, open) (NASDAQ_close, volume)
```

I want to remove everything after the underscore and append whatever comes after the comma to get the following:

```
df:
NYSE_close  NYSE_open  NYSE_volume  NASDAQ_close  NASDAQ_open  NASDAQ_volume
```

I tried to strip the column name but it replaced it with nan. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to extract the appropriate parts of the column names to replace them with:

```
import re

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['(NYSE_close, close)','(NYSE_close, open)','(NYSE_close, volume)', '(NASDAQ_close, close)','(NASDAQ_close, open)','(NASDAQ_close, volume)'])
df.columns = [re.sub(r'\(([^_]+_)\w+, (\w+)\)', r'\1\2', c) for c in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [NYSE_close, NYSE_open, NYSE_volume, NASDAQ_close, NASDAQ_open, NASDAQ_volume]
Index: []
```

Comment: Your current solution gives me this error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Which version of python/pandas are you using? This works on 3.9/1.2

Comment: I am using 3.10.4. I am not sure why exactly this error is coming out. My column names are objects

Comment: @MathMan99 did you sort it out? In your question the column names are strings, are they actually tuples? In that case you would want something like `df.columns = [f"{c[0].split('_')[0]}_{c[1]}" for c in df.columns]`

Comment: I sorted it out. They are tuples, sorry for not being very clear on that. Thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
import re

def cvt_col(x):
    s = re.sub('[()_,]', ' ', x).split()
    return s[0] + '_' + s[2] 

df.rename(columns = cvt_col)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [NYSE_close, NYSE_open, NYSE_volume, NASDAQ_close, NASDAQ_open, NASDAQ_volume]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension, twice:

```py
step1 = [ent.strip('()').split(',') for ent  in df]

df.columns = ["_".join([left.split('_')[0], right.strip()]) 
              for left, right  in step1]

df

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [NYSE_close, NYSE_open, NYSE_volume, NASDAQ_close, NASDAQ_open, NASDAQ_volume]
Index: []
```